# How to calculate df.cummin() piecewise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to start `df.cummin()` when `cond` column is true until recompute `df.cummin()` next `cond` column is true.

The result is assigned to `expected` column

input

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A=[17,18,21,15,18,19,22,16,30,50,]
cond=[False,True,False,False,False,True,False,False,True,False]
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'cond':cond})
df
```

the expected table

```
    A   cond    expected
0   17  FALSE   
1   18  TRUE    18
2   21  FALSE   18
3   15  FALSE   15
4   18  FALSE   15
5   19  TRUE    19
6   22  FALSE   19
7   16  FALSE   16
8   30  TRUE    30
9   50  FALSE   30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to groupby the cumsum of the cond column. Since you don't want any values up until the first True, you need to essentially delete values for group zero.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A=[17,18,21,15,18,19,22,16,30,50,]
cond=[False,True,False,False,False,True,False,False,True,False]
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'cond':cond})


df['expected'] = df.groupby(df.cond.cumsum())['A'].cummin()
df.loc[df.cond.cumsum().eq(0), 'expected'] = np.nan
```

Output

```
    A   cond  expected
0  17  False       NaN
1  18   True      18.0
2  21  False      18.0
3  15  False      15.0
4  18  False      15.0
5  19   True      19.0
6  22  False      19.0
7  16  False      16.0
8  30   True      30.0
9  50  False      30.0
```

Comment: Okay this is arguably better than my reply. Take this solution.

Comment: Thanks, this method is very concise and efficient, is there a faster way without `groupby`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of something with a single-line fix so I made something work with a loop:

```
# First get a list of all the index on which to reset the cummin()
my_ix = df[df['cond']].index
return_list = []
# Loop over all chunks of indexes
for i in range(0, len(my_ix)):
    ix_start = my_ix[i]
    try:
        ix_end = my_ix[i+1]
    except IndexError:
        # This happens on the last record
        ix_end = None

    cummin_df = df[ix_start:ix_end]['A'].cummin()
    return_list.append(cummin_df)
pd.concat(return_list)
```

This gives the expected result, only the first record is missing as it starts with cond=False and the expected column is empty. If you like you can populate the output first with all rows before the first row with cond=True.

If you like you can condense the code but that would make it a bit less readable.

Comment: why for loop is so much faster than groupby

Comment: Pandas methods may carry a bit more overhead but sometime scale better. If you are concerned about speed make sure to take a testset which is of similar size to your final problem. Then you can use the %timeit function to choose which approach works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

another approach using apply and cython or numba

if the data frame is small(some where under 1k records)

this could be a better option

```py
def cython_func():
    _c = False
    _min = None
    def cummin(x, engine):
        nonlocal _min, _c
        if x[1]:
            _c = True
            _min = None
        if not _c:
             return np.nan
        if _min is None or _min > x[0]:
            _min = x[0]
        return _min
    return cummin

df['expected'] = df.apply(cython_func(), engine='cython', raw=True, axis=1)
```

```py
@numba.jit()
def numba_func():
    _c = False
    _min = None
    def cummin(cond, value):
        nonlocal _min, _c
        if cond:
            _c = True
            _min = None
        if not _c:
             return np.nan
        if _min is None or _min > value:
            _min = value
        return _min
    return cummin

df['expected'] = df.apply(lambda x: numba_func()(x[0], x[1]), raw=True, axis=1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jpTb.png)

Comment: The second method reports an error:LoweringError

`Failed at object (object mode backend)`

Comment: @July not sure why...